# ClassCastException when switching Fragments into container

Tags: android, android-fragments, classcastexception

My app has an Activity which has a layout that holds 3 Fragments. The Left and middle fragments are lists where the right hand Fragment is details.

I have created a method called onArticleSelected which passes in a boolean whether the user longclicked the left list or not. if it was a long click the fragment CareAwayDatesFragment will load, whereas if a short click the Fragment CarerAwayListFragment will load.

I'm getting a ClassCastException on OnPrepareOptionsMenu. If Fragment CareAwayDatesFragment is loaded first then i short click the left list, i get this Exception.

I want different options to load in the menu depending on which Fragment is loaded.

Does anyone know why i'm getting this Exception?

Thanks in advance.

```
@Override
    public void onArticleSelected(String carerId, String _carerFirstName, String _carerLastName, String carerTelno, boolean longClick) {

        Log.e(TAG, "onArticleSelected CarerAwayActivity");

        if(longClick == true){
        Log.e(TAG, "longClick = true");


                this.carerID = carerId;
                this.carerFirstName = _carerFirstName;
                this.carerLastName = _carerLastName;


                View carerAwayDateTimeFragment = findViewById(R.id.carerawaydatetimefragment_container);

                if (carerAwayDateTimeFragment != null ) {



                Fragment newFragment = new CarerAwayDateTimeFragment();


                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
                // and add the transaction to the back stack
                transaction.replace(R.id.carerawaydatetimefragment_container, newFragment);
                //transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                // Commit the transaction
                transaction.commit();


                }else{

                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayCarerAwayDateTimeFragmentActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("carerid", carerId);
                    intent.putExtra("carerfirstname", carerFirstName);
                    intent.putExtra("carerlastname", carerLastName);

                    startActivity(intent);


                }

        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, "longClick = false");    

            this.carerID = carerId;
            this.carerFirstName = _carerFirstName;
            this.carerLastName = _carerLastName;


            View carerAwayDateTimeFragment = findViewById(R.id.carerawaydatetimefragment_container);

            if (carerAwayDateTimeFragment != null ) {

                DateTime dt = new DateTime();
                DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("d-MMM-Y");
                String from = fmt.print(dt);
                String to = fmt.print(dt);

                String[] params = new String[] { from, to, carerId};
                AsyncGetCarerAwayDates agcad = new AsyncGetCarerAwayDates();
                agcad.execute(params);

            }else{

//              Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayCarerListFragmentActivity.class);
//              intent.putExtra("carerid", carerId);
//              intent.putExtra("carerfirstname", carerFirstName);
//              intent.putExtra("carerlastname", carerLastName);
//              
//              startActivity(intent);


            }
        }

    }//end of onArticleSelected
```

.

```
@Override
     public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

        CarerListFragment carerListFragment = (CarerListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.carerlist);
        CarerAwayListFragment carerAwayListFragment = (CarerAwayListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.carerawaydatetimefragment_container);

        if(carerListFragment != null && carerAwayListFragment != null){

             menu.getItem(0).setVisible(false);
             menu.getItem(1).setVisible(false);
             menu.getItem(2).setVisible(false);
             menu.getItem(3).setVisible(false);
             menu.getItem(4).setVisible(true);
             menu.getItem(5).setVisible(false);
             menu.getItem(6).setVisible(false);



        }else{

             menu.getItem(0).setVisible(false);
             menu.getItem(1).setVisible(false);
             menu.getItem(2).setVisible(false);
             menu.getItem(3).setVisible(false);
             menu.getItem(4).setVisible(false);
             menu.getItem(5).setVisible(false);
             menu.getItem(6).setVisible(false);

        }
```

.

```
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580): Process: com.carefreegroup.rr3.carefreeoncall, PID: 15580
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.carefreegroup.rr3.carefreeoncall.CarerAwayDateTimeFragment cannot be cast to com.carefreegroup.rr3.carefreeoncall.CarerAwayListFragment
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at com.carefreegroup.rr3.carefreeoncall.CarerAwayActivity.onPrepareOptionsMenu(CarerAwayActivity.java:514)
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at android.app.Activity.onPreparePanel(Activity.java:2643)
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPrepareOptionsPanel(FragmentActivity.java:469)
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnPrepareOptionsPanel(ActionBarActivity.java:284)
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onPrepareOptionsPanel(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:204)
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onPrepareOptionsPanel(ActionBarActivity.java:256)
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPreparePanel(FragmentActivity.java:458)
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnPreparePanel(ActionBarActivity.java:280)
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.onPreparePanel(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:84)
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.preparePanel(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:1006)
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.doInvalidatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:1182)
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.access$100(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:79)
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase$1.run(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:115)
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:572)
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5350)
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
07-27 15:45:54.389: E/AndroidRuntime(15580):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Seems like

```
View carerAwayDateTimeFragment = findViewById(R.id.carerawaydatetimefragment_container);
```

is only a View but you're trying to cast it to inappropriate type.

2) This approach is not good and well organized. You can specify menus for each of the fragment separately in each fragment.

In `onCreate` method specify `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` and override `onCreateOptionsMenu` inside the fragment.

You don't need to cast anything and find fragments. Each fragment will handle menu for itself.

Comment: Hi, i need View carerAwayDateTimeFragment = findViewById(R.id.carerawaydatetimefragment_container); because if it returns null then the app must be running on a phone and loads DisplayCarerAwayDateTimeFragmentActivity

Comment: works like a charm and alot cleaner code. thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

**Use `findFragmentById()`**

You are getting back the Frame or whatever container you are using by calling this :

```
View carerAwayDateTimeFragment = findViewById(R.id.carerawaydatetimefragment_container);
```

Instead, do this :

CarerAwayDateTimeFragment carerAwayDateTimeFragment = findFragmentById(R.id.carerawaydatetimefragment_container);

Use `findFragmentById()` instead of `findViewById()` and Change the variable to the fragment class type.

Comment: hi, it says findFragmentById() is undefined for Activity, so can't use it

Comment: this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById() try this?